# Getting the actual origins of subviews iOS sdk

Tags: objective-c, frame

I have on view with frame

```
_SceneImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 95, 984, 558);
```

and I.m adding a subview to this _SceneImageView with frame

```
subview.frame = CGRectMake(325, 220, 200, 200);
```

now I want add that subview to another view with frame

```
anotherView.frame = CGRectMake(450, 110, 512, 405);
```

how can I convert the rect of subview from bigger view to smaller view???

There are two image views, _SceneImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 95, 984, 558);
and other in anotherView.frame = CGRectMake(450, 110, 512, 405);

I add one subview to _SceneImageView, now i want to convert the rect of subview with respect to "anotherView" (anotherView is smaller version of _SceneImageView)

Comment: i don't really know what you tried to do here. You can of course use: `[anotherView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)]`. But you already know that. So please post some more details.

Comment: what is the problem with `convertRect:toView:` or `convertRect:fromView:`?

Comment: my question is, how to use those methods (convertRect:toView: or convertRect:fromView:) in thys case??

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-(CGRect)convertRect:fromView:`.  For example:

```
CGRect subFrame;
CGRect sceneFrame;

// root frame
_SceneImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 95, 984, 558);

// sub frame
subview.frame         = CGRectMake(325, 220, 200, 200);

// frame with coordinates from root view
sceneFrame        = CGRectMake(450, 110, 512, 405);

// convert coordinates from root view to coordinates for subview
subFrame          = [subview convertRect:sceneFrame fromView:_SceneImageView];

anotherView.frame = subFrame;
```

Comment: thanx for the reply...but its not working...i want to convert subviews frame not the other views frame, i want the relative frame of the subview with respect to "anotherView"